# PayPal API: Exception: 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

Tags: php, paypal, oauth-2.0

The specific `401` error message I get is:

`"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"The client credentials are invalid"}"`

This error isn't listed anywhere in the PayPal documentation.  I am certain I am using the test credentials and using the correct sandbox endpoint.  The error occurs when I attempt to get an access token.

This is the class where the access token is retrieved:

```
private function _generateAccessToken($config) {

$base64ClientID = base64_encode($this->clientId . ":" . $this->clientSecret);                           
$headers = array(
    "User-Agent" => PPUserAgent::getValue(RestHandler::$sdkName, RestHandler::$sdkVersion), 
    "Authorization" => "Basic " . $base64ClientID,
    "Accept" => "*/*"
);      
$httpConfiguration = $this->getOAuthHttpConfiguration($config); 
$httpConfiguration->setHeaders($headers); 

$connection = PPConnectionManager::getInstance()->getConnection($httpConfiguration, $config);
//print_r($connection); die;
$res = $connection->execute("grant_type=client_credentials");       

$jsonResponse = json_decode($res, true);
if($jsonResponse == NULL || 
        !isset($jsonResponse["access_token"]) || !isset($jsonResponse["expires_in"]) ) {
    $this->accessToken = NULL;
    $this->tokenExpiresIn = NULL;   
    $this->logger->warning("Could not generate new Access token. Invalid response from server: " . $jsonResponse);      
} else {
    $this->accessToken = $jsonResponse["access_token"];
    $this->tokenExpiresIn = $jsonResponse["expires_in"];
}
$this->tokenCreateTime = time();
return $this->accessToken;
}
```

This is the `$connection` variable I have when I `print_r` (I removed the authorization string):

```
PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection Object( [httpConfig:PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection:private] => PayPal\Core\PPHttpConfig Object ( [headers:PayPal\Core\PPHttpConfig:private] => Array ( [User-    Agent] => PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-php 0.6.0 (lang=PHP;v=5.4.21;bit=64;os=Linux_2.6.18-    308.16.1.el5;machine=x86_64;openssl=0.9.8e-fips-rhel5;curl=7.24.0) [Authorization] => Basic     REMOVED AUTHORIZATION STRING == [Accept] => */* ) [curlOptions:PayPal\Core\PPHttpConfig:private]     => Array ( [32] => 3 [78] => 30 [19913] => 1 [13] => 60 [10018] => PayPal-PHP-SDK [10023] => Array ( ) [81] => 2 [64] => 1 ) [url:PayPal\Core\PPHttpConfig:private] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token [method:PayPal\Core\PPHttpConfig:private] => POST [retryCount:PayPal\Core\PPHttpConfig:private] => 1 ) [logger:PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection:private] => PayPal\Core\PPLoggingManager Object ( [loggerName:PayPal\Core\PPLoggingManager:private] => PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection [isLoggingEnabled:PayPal\Core\PPLoggingManager:private] => 1 [loggingLevel:PayPal\Core\PPLoggingManager:private] => 3 [loggerFile:PayPal\Core\PPLoggingManager:private] => PayPal.log ))
```

As far I can tell, I have correct credentials, correct endpoint, not sure what else it could be?

Comment: I'm also having this problem. My sandbox accounts were working just fine last week, but now all of a sudden, they're not.

Comment: Please let me know if you find a solution, I'll do the same!

Comment: Well crap, my issue ended up being a WordPress problem: I was trying to hit the live API, not the Sandbox API. That's what "credentials" means, apparently: the API settings, not the card number, which I suspected at first. You're not using WordPress too, are you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A HTTP401 on /token is returned if the client_id/secret aren’t recognized (either the wrong credentials for the environment, or the credentials aren’t active).

Can you run a test via cURL to rule out any environment / code-specific issues?

```
curl -v -u "client_id:secret" "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token" -X POST -d "response_type=token&grant_type=client_credentials"
```

(Replace client_id and secret above with your own)

Comment: I ran the cUrl test and it did return my access token. I copied and pasted my credentials from my code.  I used the same sandbox endpoint as well.  If it's not my credentials and not my endpoint, what else could it be?  What else could invalidate my credentials?

Comment: The issue ended up being the SDK config file.  I thought the constants.php file gave access to the credentials throughout the SDK.  I added the credentials to the sdkconfig as well.

Comment: I am also getting this error. How did you add the credentials to sdkconfig? I was not able to find this file anywhere in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure payment $config mode is Sandbox and clientId and clientSecret keys are Sandbox same time.